# Resize inner dimension of 2D vector

Tags: c++, vector

I want to create a vector with inner dimension having a initialize size of 10 and outer dimension can have any size which grows dynamically:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>>;
```

The inner must have an initial size of 10. Is this possible ?

Comment: If you are using C++11 you could use a std::array for the inner components.

Comment: @ilent2: He said initial size, not  fix size.

Comment: @Melkon Good point, I wasn't sure if he wanted the inner dimension to change or only the outer dimension.

Comment: If all inner vectors will always have the same size, then IMHO using a "two layer" vector isn't ideal, better use a single `vector<int>` with `rows * columns` elements (unless you have a lot of elements, then having noncontinuous storage may be a plus)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible to initialize the size of the inner vectors to 10:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> foo(n, // will contain n inner vectors
    std::vector<int>(10)); // each inner vector has size 10 initially
```

Comment: `foo(n, {10})` Here `{10}` = `initializer_list<int>` of 1 element 10??

Comment: @user2079303 `std::vector<int>{10}` and `std::vector<int>(10)` do not give same behaviour. The first one gives a vector of 10 elements unitialized and the second one gives a vector of one element which has value 10.

Comment: Right, so it is. I removed that suggestion from the answer, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When you use vector of vectors, the inner vector is also dynamic in nature. You just declare and initialize it when defining the inner vector, then push it to outer vector.

```
const int col_size = 10;
vector<vector<int> > table;
vector<int> row(col_size, 0);
table.push_back(row);
```

Code below defines an array of size n*m and filled with 0: (noting that this does not restrict the dimension of vector appended in future)

```
const int m = 5, n = 4;
vector<vector<int> > arr(n, vector<int>(m,0));
```

An alternative approach is to define your own structure for inner dimension using static type:

```
const int col_size = 3;
struct Row {
    int val[col_size];
    // to behave like an array.
    int operator[](int x) { return val[x]; }
};
vector<Row> table;
```

Answer (score 0):

As others here, mentioned that while using vectors you probably dont have to worry about allocation/de-allocation, std::vector can grow their sizes if required. if you want to use fixed (some what fixed, which which change if some new elements are pushed) size vector you can use can reserve slots by using **std::vector::reserve**